# Go to next empty cell in column B

Tags: vba, button, listbox

im trying to create a button for my listbox to go to the next empty cell un column B. when i use this code it goes to the last empty cell in column A. please help. thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
 Dim i As Long
 With lstOCC
 For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
 Debug.Print i, lstOCC.List(i, 0)
 If lstOCC.Column(i, 0) <> "" Then
 .ListIndex = i
 Exit For
 End If
 Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `lstOCC.List(i, 1)`.

Comment: it goes to the end of the blank list. not the next empty row below my filled columns

Comment: I you do not show us "your filled columns" we cannot understand what you try doing. I only changed the column to be returned and I do not even know how you implemented my suggestion. It goes to the first empty row iterating backwards. I do not understand what you try doing.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. you got it correct. thanks